# Digital buffer/driver (74LVC1G07) not outputting signal. MIDI output circuit

Tags: output, buffer, midi

I am expericing difficulties with a simple MIDI output circuit. I have checked the input of the buffer and signal is there. However, there is not signal at ouput. [image: Sketch for MIDI in and out circuit].

At first I thought that I blew up the output buffer so I changed it for a new one. I didn't have the same package available so I fitted a bigger package in the best way possible. [image]

Any ideas why the 74LVC1G07 doesn't output signal?

Comment: Is the power supply OK?

Comment: The device is open collector - have you provided a load?

Comment: Have you connected it to a load to actually see the signal? Shorting pins 4 to 5 on output connector should be simplest way to see the signal at the point you measure.

Answer (score 4):

MIDI is open collector on the driver side, expecting an opto coupler in the receiver. Schematic and explanation is [here](http://www.muzines.co.uk/articles/practically-midi/2509). So you need to either plug in the receiver or simulate it with a resistor which you temporarily add. (A 5 pin DIN with an LED from pins 4 to 5 is a useful tool if you work on this stuff much.)

Comment: The suggested test with the resistor and LED helped me to find out that one of the leads was not solder properly.